# Using an applet to access a session used by the browser asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, applet

I have a page (asp.net) that has an applet that communicates with the server in order to verify some requirements. The scenario is:

- It connects using **`URLHttpConnection`**, not by javascript's `submit` or `ajax` methods such as `GET` or `POST`,
- The server is a **regular** `Asp.Net` website,
- I intercept those requests using **`HttpHandlers`**,
- I am quite aware of **`IRequireSessionState`**,
- The session authentication is made by **Forms Authentication**, and the **session that was authenticated was the browser's**, not the one that the applet uses.

My question is:

How can I get the session that the browser is using?
I suppose I could store, somewhere, the `sessionId`, send it in the request and try to retrieve the session in the handler, but how could I do it?

Keep in mind that:

- I can not get the cookies of the browser, because the request was made in the applet,
- I don't have access to the source of the applet, as it is a partner's black box,
- I can, though, send as many parameters in the request as I need (the applet has a function that permits it).

Thanks